# How to evenly distribute variable height blocks among columns?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, flexbox

I'm doing this in JavaScript, but I suppose this can be a general enough since I'm asking more about the algorithm.

I have a menu, in a flexbox column layout.

- Has three columns on desktop,
- Two columns on tablet.
- One on mobile.
- Website admins are able to add new items to the menu as they please, This consists of a series of parent and child links.
- The order of the blocks should appear as they were entered by the admins.
- A parent serves as a heading, and children listed underneath. Each parent/child set serves as a single block that should appear in the layout, without being broken up.
- Each parent/child set can have a different height,
- We have space to grow the entire container as needed.
- Columns should be as evenly distributed as possible, and avoid breaking into a 4th column (on desktop - or 3rd on tablet).

How can I determine what the height of the entire container should be to accommodate this?

Leaving no max-height is fine for mobile, but for tablet and desktop that will just allow all the elements to all occupy the first column, without moving to the next. I will need to set a max-height, which will impose a breakpoint to start each new column. The problem with this is if all elements don't fit into the columns, with the height I set, they could break into a 4th column, and determining this height seems trickier than at first thought.

We can't simply add up all the heights of each block, and divide by the number of columns. Some elements will be so large that they take up most of a column, not leaving enough space for any additional elements, so the space between the end of that block, and the container is wasted. Likewise, any combination of larger/smaller elements will inevitably end up with some wasted space between the end of the elements and the total height of the container.

I'm envisioning an algorithm like this:

First, iterate over the elements, collect the following data points, height of each in an array, the height of the largest element, the total number of blocks, and the total sum of all their heights.

Divide by the desired number of columns (as determined by getting the screen size and comparing with breakpoint widths).

Determine an absolute minimum height, if the largest element exceeds the height/number of columns, than use that as the absolute minimum, otherwise use the result of dividing by the columns.

I still need to determine the amount of wasted space I need to accommodate, and this is where I get stuck. So far, I've resorted to simply adding 200px of additional height to accommodate everything. But it's kind of a dumb approach, and still can potentially run into issues of blocks breaking into a 4th column.   Here is an idea I'm working with though.

It would be nice to know how many columns flexbox breaks something into, but I haven't been able to figure that out

Create an array to represent the columns. Iterate over all the blocks again. Get the height of each element, add those heights to the array position representing the column. If adding a block would cause you to exceed the absolute minimum height determined above, add it to the next column instead. Repeat this for all elements. At the end, count the number of excess columns you end up with, of these, determine which one has the greatest height of it's blocks, and add that value to the total minimum height of the container we established from before.

I think this algorithm will run the risk of adding too much height however.  Can this be better?

Here is my code so far:

```
      var resizeOverlayMenu = function() {
    var oneColumBreakpoint = 750;
    var twoColumnBreakpoint = 1000;
    var columns = 3; // Default to desktop - but mobile first!?
    var minElementHeight = 0;
    var totalHeight = 0;
    var averageHeight = 0;
    var finalHeight = '1037px';
    var mainMenuFirst = $('.overlay__first .menu--main');
    var mainMenuChildren = $('.overlay__first .menu--main .menu__item.has-subnav');
    var addtlHeight = 50;
    var childHeights = [];

    mainMenuChildren.each(function() {
      var childHeight = $(this).height();
      childHeights.push(childHeight);
      totalHeight = totalHeight + childHeight;
      if (childHeight > minElementHeight) {
        minElementHeight = childHeight;
      }
    });

    // Figure out the screen size and breakpoints

    // Mobile
    if (window.screen.width <= oneColumBreakpoint ) {
      columns = 1;
      addtlHeight = 50;
    }
    // Tablet
    else if (window.screen.width > oneColumBreakpoint && window.screen.width <= twoColumnBreakpoint ) {
      columns = 2;
      addtlHeight = 200;
    }
    // Else leave the default

    // TODO: Check if the overlay width at this point is wider than the screen. That means we've still pushed to 3
    //  columns. So let's just add enough to the height to accommodate those remaining items.

    averageHeight = totalHeight / columns;

    if (minElementHeight > averageHeight) {
      finalHeight = minElementHeight + addtlHeight;
    }
    else if (averageHeight !== 0) {
      finalHeight = averageHeight + addtlHeight;
    }
    // Now set the height on the overlay.
    mainMenuFirst.css({height: finalHeight});
    mainMenuFirst.css({'min-height': finalHeight});
  };
```

Edit: Someone shared this Wikipedia link on [Multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning) (then their comment disappeared). This helps give me some language to what I am trying to describe, but one thing I need is to preserve order, and I'm not sure this does that.

Comment: Would be incredible if you write requirements as listed items in short.

Comment: @NecatiTuran Thanks for the suggestion, tried to break it out. Added the current state of my code as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the problem is: given an array of numbers, split it into three bins so that the sums of the bins differ as little as possible.

Given there are only three bins and you'll hardly deal with millions of elements, it's fine to go with the brute force: compute all possible splits and choose one whose euclidian distance to the ideal split (`sum(arr)/3`) is minimal:

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 8]

function sum(a) {
    return a.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)
}

let bestSplit = null
let bestDist = Infinity

let eq = sum(arr) / 3

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
        let a = arr.slice(0, i)
        let b = arr.slice(i, k)
        let c = arr.slice(k)

        let dist = (sum(a) - eq) ** 2 + (sum(b) - eq) ** 2 + (sum(c) - eq) ** 2

        if (dist < bestDist) {
            bestDist = dist
            bestSplit = [a, b, c]
        }
    }
}

console.log(bestSplit.map(String).join(' | '))
```

Comment: I'd like to preserve the order as is if possible.